# intellij test fails: Please refer to ..target\surefire-reports for the individual test results

Tags: intellij-idea, junit, junit5

I want to test my java intellij project using maven and get error which is not related to
my code. To be more specific Intellij editor complains so:

> "Please refer to C:\Users\USER\IdeaProjects\testing\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results."

I added needed dependencies for unit testing im pom.xm file:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved it.
The problem was that the maven version had to be updated from 3.6.0 to 3.9.x for JDK 55.0-61.0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).